# How upgrade version pip by proxy?

Tags: proxy, python

for my task need install pywin32 pack.
Python can install new pack only by proxy.

```
pip --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port> install pywin32
```

But installing end error

```
Collecting pywin32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions
: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

**How upgrade version pip by proxy?**

p.s. try to use

```
pip --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port> -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

But result

```
Unknown option: --
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` is equivalent to `python -m pip`, so you can try

```
pip --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port> install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
python -m pip --proxy http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port> install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Slipeer might solve your problem of upgrading pip but I believe your underlying issue was installing pywin32.

Pywin32 isn't available through pip, it is downloadable at the project home (on SF) and comes as a Win32 installer.